# Trying to access session data from a queued job in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am building a web-app that allows people to book times with teachers. As it currently stands, once the time is added to the users cart no one else can see that this time is available or add it to their cart.

I am using [darryldecode's shopping cart](https://github.com/darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart) in which items are stored as long as the session persists (2 hours). However, I would like items to be automatically removed from it 5 minutes after being added. In order to accomplish this I have set up a queued job with a delay of 5 minutes.

My problem is that the job changes the times to become visible to other users again after 5 minutes but does not remove them from the cart as it appears not to be able to access the session in which the cart data is stored. Can anyone advise on how I might access the cart data stored in the session from a queued job?
Thanks.

This is the code for the job, everything works except for Cart::remove()

```
namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Jobs\Job;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use App\TimeSlot;
use Cart;

class RemoveTimeSlotFromCart extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

    public $timeSlot;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(TimeSlot $timeSlot)
    {
        $this->timeSlot = $timeSlot;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $timeSlot = $this->timeSlot;
        if ($timeSlot->booked == 0 && $timeSlot->in_basket == 1) {
            $timeSlot->in_basket = 0;
            $timeSlot->save();
            Cart::remove($timeSlot->id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll want to get a list of the open reservations before you trash them so you can release them from the cart. This will all need to be handled by your queued job - can you share how you're clearing them from the database currently?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by 'open reservations', sorry. Currently when a time is added to the cart it's 'in_cart' value is set to 1 in the database, and this is then automatically set back to 0 after 5 minutes by the queued job. The issue is that I cannot use the Cart facade from within the job, as the job appears not to be able to access it. Perhaps it can and I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you share the code for your job then?

Comment: Added to the initial post, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cron Jobs run in a new session. Your cart library (darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart) is session based. It will be extremely difficult to change session data (maybe impossible? depending on your session driver) if its not from the current user's browser-initiated session. Specifically, this line:

```
Cart::remove($timeSlot->id);
```

The cart model has no way of knowing from which cart to remove the item. From a UX perspective - you're going to want to give the user some feedback that their time-slot has been dropped anyway; so, writing a check-for-removal on each page draw (or asynchronously over js) shouldn't be unanticipated work.

On each page draw, loop through each item in the visitor's cart. I don't know how you've constructed the cart::add(...) to handle a unique cart item id, so this assumes timeslot ids match the cart-item ids.

```
$removed = [];
foreach(Cart::getContent() as $item) {
    $timeSlot = timeSlot::findOrFail($item->id);
    if( $timeSlot->in_basket === 0 ) {
        Cart::remove($timeSlot->id);
    }
}
if(count($removed)) {
    //inject a HTML/JS popup message like "your timeslot has been dropped because you're too slow
    //or pass it along into the request
    $request->session()->flash('slots-dropped', $removed);
}
```

This is ideally handled within a cartUpdate middleware, but could be done within controllers depending on the complexity of your site.

[EDIT] 
There is a flaw in the above solution as a result of the database structure - User A reserves a timeslot but does not checkout within the checkout window, the timeslot is returned to "not in cart" status for a few minutes before User A notices; meanwhile, User B sees the same timeslot after it has been returned to the pool of available timeslots and before User A looks at another page (and the cart updates with the appropriate messaging). At this point the timeslot is in person B's cart. When the page-refresh looks to see if Person A's timeslot is in "any" cart - it says "yes, its in a cart because $timeslot->in_basket == 1 ". Person A continues checking out and gets the timeslot even though its in Person B's cart.

The fix for this is rather simple - change the datatype of in_basket from a boolean to a string and assign it the value of the session_id each time it's added to a cart. From what I can see in the cart class, that's probably app()->session->get('session'). You var_dump(app()->session->all()) to see if that's right before you commit to refactoring this throughout. The updated solution would then look like:

```
$removed = [];
foreach(Cart::getContent() as $item) {
    $timeSlot = timeSlot::findOrFail($item->id);
    if( $timeSlot->in_basket !== app()->session->get('session') ) {
        Cart::remove($timeSlot->id);
    }
}
if(count($removed)) {
    //inject a HTML/JS popup message like "your timeslot has been dropped because you're too slow
    //or pass it along into the request
    $request->session()->flash('slots-dropped', $removed);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is very helpful and I really appreciate the time you took to write it. This is a great solution for users staying on the site. For instances where users add something to their cart and then immediately leave the site, what would you recommend? Should I just have the session expire after 5 minutes?

Comment: If they've left the site, their session should expire using the natural session expiry - again, depends on the session driver you're using but often defaults to two hours, and the cart will disappear from memory. If someone leaves your site and returns within two hours - they might still expect to have a cart with their timeslot still in it... so showing them a message to the contrary would be a good UX practice. You wouldn't have to handle that situation any differently - it all follows the same logic: on each page draw, check for session/cart presence, update cart if timeslots are voided.